# Simplify $\sqrt[3]{36}*\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{3}}*\sqrt{27}$ writing each factor in index notation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I rearranged it in index form:

$$36^{\frac{1}{3}}*27^{\frac{1}{2}}*({\frac{4}{3}})^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

After this i changed 36 into 4*9 and then 9 into $$3^2$$
So 36 became:
$$3^{\frac{2}{3}}*4^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

And 27 into 
$$(3^3)^{\frac{1}{2}} =3^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Now I multiplied everything and I got
$$(4^{\frac{1}{2}}*3)/3^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Which became
$$2*3^{\frac{5}{6}}$$

And the answer in my book is 18. What did I do wrong to get a wrong result?

Comment: Please verify that the edit is correct. For future reference, `$\frac{123}{456}$` writes $\frac{123}{456}$. `\sqrt[3]{\frac{123}{456}}` writes $\sqrt[3]{\frac{123}{456}}$. `\frac{6^{frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt[5]{246}}` shows $$\frac{6^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt[5]{246}}$$

Comment: @probablyme Thank you :) Will try to make it better next time

Answer (score 2):

Your error was multiplying the exponents in the expression 
$$3^{\frac{2}{3}}3^{\frac{3}{2}}$$ 
rather than adding them, which is why you obtained $3$ in the numerator rather than $3^{\frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{2}} = 3^{\frac{13}{6}}$.
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{36}\sqrt{27}\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{3}} & = 36^{\frac{1}{3}}27^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\\
& = (3^24)^{\frac{1}{3}}(3^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{4^{\frac{1}{6}}}{{3^{\frac{1}{6}}}}\right)\\
& = 3^{\frac{2}{3}}4^{\frac{1}{3}}3^{\frac{3}{2}}4^{\frac{1}{6}}3^{-\frac{1}{6}}\\
& = 3^{\frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{6}}4^{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}}\\
& = 3^{\frac{4}{6} + \frac{9}{6} - \frac{1}{6}}4^{\frac{2}{6} + \frac{1}{6}}\\
& = 3^{\frac{12}{6}}4^{\frac{3}{6}}\\
& = 3^24^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
& = 9 \cdot 2\\
& = 18
\end{align*}

Comment: Ahh...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[3]{36}\sqrt[6]{\frac{4}{3}}\sqrt{27}&=36^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\cdot27^\frac{1}{2}\\
&=(6^2)^\frac{1}{3}(3^{-1}\cdot2^2)^\frac{1}{6}(3^3)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=[(3\cdot2)^2]^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot3^{-\frac{1}{6}}\cdot2^{\frac{2}{6}}\cdot3^\frac{3}{2}\\
&=(3\cdot2)^\frac{2}{3}\cdot3^{\frac{9}{6}-\frac{1}{6}}\cdot2^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
&=3^\frac{2}{3}\cdot3^\frac{8}{6}\cdot2^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}\\
&=3^{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}}\cdot2\\
&=3^2\cdot2\\
&=9\cdot2\\
&=18
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$36^{1\over3}*27^{1\over2}*({4\over3})^{1\over6}=$$
$$6^{2\over3}*3^{3\over2}*2^{1\over3}*3^{-1\over6}=$$
$$2^{2\over3}*3^{2\over3} *3^{3\over2}*2^{1\over3}*3^{-1\over6}=$$
$$ 2^{{2\over3}+{1\over3}}*3^{{2\over3}+{3\over2}-{1\over 6}}=2*3^2=18$$

Comment: Thats an other way to do it, thank you :)